# App Asks for Location Right After First Launch

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have an app that uses location services.

On the first launch, I want the user to press the button to turn the location services on (which brings up the system dialog asking for the location permissions)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    If firstLaunch {
      showPermissionsView() 

    } else {
      locationManager = CLLocationManager()
      locationManager?.delegate = self
      locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    }    
}
```

The issue here is when I do a fresh install to debug, the system asks for location permissions right away on the first launch. This is before the user presses the button.

Few notes:

1. App has no other `CLLocationManager()` anywhere else in the project.
2. App does have a Widget target that uses location (not sure if it's connected here).
3. `self.locationManager` has not even initiated or called by the time the system asks for location permissions.

Comment: can add your full code?

Comment: @PratikPrajapati unfortunately I cannot.

Comment: At least show how `firstLaunch` is `true` on a first launch.  It seems likely that it is `false`.